# Forcing program to create coredump on freebsd

Tags: c, operating-system, freebsd, coredump

In my project I added a new module and now my process is being terminated by signal 11 . 
I want to track and understand the problem but no coredump file is generated by freebsd. 
I set sysctl like :

```
sysctl -a | grep core
kern.corefile: /usr/core
kern.nodump_coredump: 1
kern.coredump: 1
kern.sugid_coredump: 1
debug.elf64_legacy_coredump: 1
debug.elf32_legacy_coredump: 1
```

I also set ulimit -c unlimited

From my code I removed all code about signal like  "sigaction(SIGTERM, &signal, &signal_old);"
for not preventing kernel to generate coredump.

Why I can't see any coredump still ? What I am missing ?

Also are there any method forcing a program which run on freebsd to create coredump an equivalent to do_coredump() in linux?

Comment: Usually to force a core dump you would call raise(signum) where signum is a signal that produces an exit with a core dump (abort, seg, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in:

`kern.corefile: /usr/core`

Something like the following should help:

`sysctl -w kern.corefile = "%N.core"`

Comment: I worked 2 hours on that and your advise work thanks . But there is one problem now the core is being created in "tmp" folder . My program runs on VM and I give so little disk space.The tmp partition is so small I want to core to be created under usr . Do you have any magic for that also?

Comment: Sure, try something like sysctl -w kern.corefile = "/usr/core/%N.core" - specifying a directory that exists and is writable

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, kern.corefile is the complete name of the resulting corefile, not the directory in which it should be placed. It also needs to be writable by the user running the process. /usr/core looks like a directory and/or a location writable only by root.

kern.nodump_coredump: 1 also looks suspicious.I don't remember that sysctl existing in the last version of FreeBSD I used, but it looks like it's intended to disable core dumps. Try setting it to 0.

Comment: It turn out kern.nodump_coredump: 1 is correct . Only thing was "%N" thanks anyway